# Pip Install Arkouda fails even when Chapel installed

Tags: numpy, pip, chapel

I'm attempting to install the [PyPi client](https://pypi.org/project/arkouda/) to [Arkouda](https://github.com/mhmerrill/arkouda)

```
> pip install arkouda

...
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-8y41snys/arkouda/installers.py", line 60, in custom_run
        raise ArkoudaBuildError("Chapel is not installed, Arkouda cannot be built")
    installers.ArkoudaBuildError: Chapel is not installed, Arkouda cannot be built
```

But this shows

```
> chpl --version
chpl version 1.23.0 pre-release (63dade1a2b)
Copyright 2020 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP
Copyright 2004-2019 Cray Inc.
(See LICENSE file for more details)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arkouda installer [is looking for the `CHPL_HOME` environment variable](https://github.com/mhmerrill/arkouda/blob/6de62d263e831fb55e6978e89f3e36952e16d2ac/installers.py#L14). Define one and retry installation.

Comment: Assuming this answer is correct, it seems like it'd be worth filing a GitHub issue requesting a better error message (or different test for Chapel installation) against the Arkouda project's issues page:  https://github.com/mhmerrill/arkouda/issues

Comment: I ended up filing https://github.com/mhmerrill/arkouda/issues/410 against this so that I could close this tab without guilt.